# Is there a MySQL Docker image for ARM64 that works like the official image?

Tags: mysql, docker, arm64

I'm trying see what kind of performance I can get out of an Amazon Graviton instance. I have a compose file that pulls official images off Docker Hub. No problem with Node. No problem with Nginx. No problem with WordPress. MySQL, however, doesn't work. Apparently there's no Docker image for that on ARM.

I tried using an 3-rd party MySQL image built for ARM but it doesn't seem to use ENV variables in the same manner as the official image.

Comment: If you after just a comparison, dockerhub mariadb has ARM64 and x86_64 (and ppc64le) in the same form so ENV variables would be consistent.

Comment: @danblack Perfect. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

`ARM64` is [being supported](https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/) with mySQL 8.0 (only); here's the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/Dockerfile).

Comment: [Work is in progress](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/318) to get this to dockerhub, otherwise [mariadb?](http://soaphub.org/imagehub/?q=mariadb&n=library&p=0)

Comment: The image `mysql-server` is _built specifically for Linux platforms. Other platforms are not supported, and users using these MySQL Docker images on them are doing so at their own risk._ as stated in the readme. (So be careful if your host no Linux system)

Answer (score 2):

The [`mysql`](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) image has `arm64v8` support since v8: https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8/mysql/

Answer (score -3):

Update minor version of your MySQL container to the latest one,
I updated from 5.7.22 to 5.7.37 and it works now fine.